# User Permissions from django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I have the model Profile related with model User by OneToOne:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
...
```

Also i have the model Books related with model Profile by ForeignKey:

```
class Books(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
...
```

admin.py:

```
class ProfileInLine(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
...
```

I need to create user in django admin, and that user:

1. Can login in django admin
2. Can edit and see his data (Profile and User models)
3. Can edit only his Books

I will appreciate for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new admin user

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

then go into django admin and:

- deselect super user
- desleect all permissions you don't want to give them

then save the admin user